# Zend2 isolated module configs

Tags: zend-framework2

It seem that all config settings defined in `Module.php` in `getConfig` method are merged globally across the application. It's pretty weird for my case, because I need different configs for each module: database settings, some factories and view_manager settings which are currently overridden by the last module loaded. How can I use configs exclusive for some module is scope of `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')` in that module. The only thoughts I have now are to merge my module config with `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')` on dispatch event, if that is the only case, what priority is better to use so I can utilize all settings: view_manager, service_manager ect?

For me the ideal solution will be if configs settings in scope of some namespace will be used only under that namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest your configuration values as deeply as you like.

Imaging you've got a module called "mymodule", and it needs to connect to a special, module-specific database (distinct from the main DB for the overall application).  You would do something like this:

**mymodule.global.php.dist:**

```
return array(
    'mymodule' => array(
        'db' => array('host'=>'localhost', ... )
    )
)
```

Then just make sure that myModule is looking at `$config['mymodule']['db']`, and not `$config['db']`

Comment: Pretty much as described in here. If there's specific configuration, add the namespace as your first level of your configuration array and have everything else beneath it. This is the way all major modules out there do it, too ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the configuration settings of the module in this way:

```
$moduleManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ModuleManager');
$applicationModule = $moduleManager->getModule('Application');
$applicationConfig = $applicationModule->getConfig();
```